# convert factor to date in R to create dummy variable

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I need to create dummy variable for "before and after 04/11/2020" for variable "date" in dataset "counties". There are over hundred dates in the dataset. I am trying to covert the dates from factor to date with as.date function, but get NA. Could you please help finding where I am making an error? I kept the other dummy variable I created just in case, if it affects the overall outcome

```
counties <- read.csv('C:/Users/matpo/Desktop/us-counties.csv')
str(counties)
as.Date(counties$date, format = '%m/%d/%y')
#create dummy variables forNew York, New Jersey, California, and Illinois
counties$state = ifelse(counties$state == 'New Jersey' & 
               counties$state == 'New York'& counties$state == 'California' & 
               counties$state == 'Illinois', 1, 0)
counties$date = ifelse(counties$date >= "4/11/2020", 1, 0)
```

str output

```
 $ date  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ county: Factor w/ 1774 levels "Abbeville","Acadia",..: 1468 1468 1468 379 1468 1178 379 1468 979 942 ...
 $ state : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fips  : int  53061 53061 53061 17031 53061 6059 17031 53061 4013 6037 ...
 $ cases : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deaths: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...``
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an incorrect format in `as.Date`, you should use `"%Y"` for 4 digit year.
2. You need to assign the values back (`<-`) for the values to change.
3. `"4/11/2020"` is just a string, if you are comparing date you need to convert it to date object. Also you can avoid using `ifelse` here.

Try :

```
counties$date <- as.Date(counties$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
counties$dummy <- as.integer(counties$date >= as.Date('2020-04-11'))
```

Comment: Strangely enough you can compare character to date if the format isn't ambiguous - `as.Date("2020-01-01") < c("2019-12-31","2020-01-02")` - it's not good practice but it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it does work but both the vectors are compared as characters and not as dates. Same as `"1" < "10"` works.

Comment: I'm not sure that is strictly true - `as.Date("2020-01-01") == "2020-01-1"` and `"2020-01-01" == "2020-01-1"` give different results for instance.